# Limit and Animate Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, jquery-animate

I'm sure there are already plenty of answers to this question already out there but the problem is I don't know what to search. I'm basically looking to use the animate function to move an element up when the user puts their mouse over another object and move it back when they move their mouse out. I got it to work fine but I'm not sure how to limit it so that they can't move the mouse in and out of the element a bunch of times really fast and then stop leaving the object continuing to animate for as many times as they entered the element.

```
$('.cover_1').mouseover(function() {
    $('.pop_1').animate({bottom: "0px"}, 100);
}).mouseout(function(){
    $('.pop_1').animate({bottom: "-300px"}, 100);
});
```

This is the code I have now.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using the [stop method](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) like so:

```
$('.cover_1').mouseover(function() {
    $('.pop_1').stop(true,true).animate({bottom: "0px"}, 100);
}).mouseout(function(){
    $('.pop_1').stop(true, true).animate({bottom: "-300px"}, 100);
});
```

Comment: Great that worked! Thanks. I have another question real quick. Why is it that the mouseover and mouseout functions respond even with the elements inside of the object. Like when I scroll over some text inside of the .cover_1 element it reacts as though I'm leaving it.

Comment: probably bad css to be honest

Comment: I figured out it was because the over/out functions don't support child objects. I just changed them to enter/leave. Thanks for the help.